# what is const keyword necessary

Tags: c++, reference, constants

My code does not compile.

```
int foobar()
{
    // code
    return 5;
}

int main()
{
   int &p = foobar(); // error
   // code

   const int& x = foobar(); //compiles
}
```

Why does adding the keyword *const* make the code compile?

Comment: If you remove the `&` ie make it a value not a reference it will also work.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In C++ temporaries cannot be bound to non-constant references.

In

```
 int &p = foobar();
```

The rvalue expression `foobar()` generates a temporary which cannot be bound to `p` because it is a non-const reference.

```
 const int &x = foobar();
```

Attaching the temporary to `x` which is a reference to const prolongs its lifetime. It is perfectly legal.

Comment: I don't quite follow. Does this implicitly cause the temporary to be stored on the stack somewhere for longer (whatever "longer" is)? Or is it that `x` gets bound to the literal 5 rather than the temporary copy of 5 created when `foobar` returns?

Answer (score 4):

Because `foobar()` is returning *by value*; this result is a temporary.  You cannot have a non-constant reference of a temporary.

If this were not true, what would this code do?

```
int &x = foobar();

x = 1;  // Where are we writing to?
```

Comment: same place we're taking the address of when we do `const int &x = foobar(); std::cout << &x;`. Temporaries with their lives extended are proper objects, they can have `mutable` data members, there's no fundamental reason they couldn't be referred to by non-const references, it just isn't allowed.

Answer (score 2):

As others have said, you can take a const but not a non-const reference to a temporary.

In practice there would be dangers in allowing non-const references to temporaries:

```
#include <iostream>
void foo(int &i) {
    i = 5;
}

int main() {
    long l = 4;
    foo(l);
    std::cout << l << "\n";
}
```

Now, `l` can be implicitly converted to `int`, so if a non-const reference to temporary were allowed here, then presumably `foo` would be passed a reference to the result of that conversion, same as it actually is if `foo` takes `const int &`. The assignment would be made to the temporary and then discarded when the temporary is destroyed. That's much more likely to be a confusing bug than it is to be the intended result.

I don't know if there's a neat set of rules to allow non-const references to temporaries in some situations but not in the dangerous/annoying ones, but even if so the C++ standard didn't include them. Note that C++0x has rvalue references, which allow you to do some extra things with temporaries that can't be done in C++03.